# Use of FileSystemObject on Windows Phone 7 - IE9 Mango (and iPhone alternative)

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, filesystemobject

Is it possible to use this on a windows phone?

```
var fsObj = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var theFile = fsObj.CreateTextFile("c:\\giantco.txt", true);
theFile.WriteLine(theData);
theFile.Close();
```

I understand that there might not be a `c:\` there - is there an alternative for both WP7 and iPhone?

Cheers!

Comment: You cant, ever, access a file on the local machine from the web. For obvious security risks. What are you actually trying to do? There are other means to save arbitrary data on the user's device, which are cross-platform.

Comment: I'm trying to save an array. Without using a database.

Comment: Try using LocalStorage, or cookies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. ActiveX does not exist on WP7. You don't have direct access to the file system from either web browser.